# How to declare instance of delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

```
private delegate void stopMachineryDelegate();
public stopMachineryDelegate StopMachinery;

this.StopMachinery += new stopMachineryDelegate(painting);
```

In the above example in the second line are we creating a delegate instance or a delegate variable? If the second line creates delegate instance of type stopMachineryDelegate, then in the third line what are we doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line is used to define your delegate type (`stopMachineryDelegate`), as a delegate accepting no parameters and returning no values (`void`).

Second line is declaring a field of that type, named `StopMachinery`. At that point, `StopMachinery` is null.

The third line has some syntactic sugar behind it. If `StopMachinery` is null at that point, it will create a new instance of that `MulticastDelegate`, and then add the `painting` method delegate to its invocation list.

If you only wanted to assign a single delegate to that field, you could have simply written:

```
 // implicitly wrap the `painting` method into a new delegate and 
 // assign to the `StopMachinery` field
 this.StopMachinery = painting;
```

On the other hand, using `+=` allows you to specify a list of delegates to be invoked when you invoke `StopMachinery`:

```
 this.StopMachinery += painting;  
 this.StopMachinery += someOtherMethod;  
 this.StopMachinery += yetAnotherMethod;
```

In the latter case, invocation of the `StopMachinery` delegate will invoke each of the methods in the invocation list, synchronously, in the order they were specified.

Comment: So when we add painting method delegate and some other delegates to the newly created MulticastDelegate instance, then does it mean that MulticastDelegate instance is referring to the instances of delegates like the painting method delegate?

Comment: @kaustav: adding delegates to the `StopMachinery` delegate using the `+=` operator adds them to an internal list inside the delegate (the "invocation list"). This operation is usually done for events, and sometimes called "attaching" (i.e. attaching a handler to an event). If you then invoke this delegate later in your program (i.e. call `StopMachinery();`), it will sequentially invoke all methods you attached to it, one by one. That is the basic idea under the "observer pattern", which is used [extensively through BCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx).

Comment: @kaustav: this pattern is used in WinForms extensively: whenever you, for example, attach a handler to a `Click` event of a `Button`, you are actually merely adding a method (wrapped in a delegate instance) to the invocation list of the `Click` multicast delegate. When a button is clicked, it will invoke all "subscribers" to that event sequentially. Note also that a proper program should (at some time) detach from this list using the `-=` operator, to avoid being invoked after it doesn't need the functionality anymore.

Comment: @kaustav: "referring to the instances of delegates"? Yes, I guess you can say that. It holds a list of references to instances of delegates. That's also why GC will never collect instance objects which hold methods which are attached to a reachable object's event until you detach them using the mentioned `-=` operator.

Answer (score 2):

On the second line you are declaring a variable of type `stopMachineryDelegate`. But at this point the variable is still unassigned having holding a default value of `null`.

On the third line you are assigning a value to this variable by creating a new instance of the delegate pointing to the `painting` function.

So once this variable is assigned you could use it to invoke the function it is pointing to:

```
this.StopMachinery();
```

which will basically invoke the `painting` method in the same class.